# How to get InputStream via Spring-Feign?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, zero-copy

I want to download and save a file in local directory from server by Spring-OpenFeign with zero-copy.

Naive download method as following:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

@GetMapping("/api/v1/files")
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@RequestParam(value = "key") String key) {
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> resp = getFile("filename.txt")
    File fs = new File("/opt/test")
    FileUtils.write(file, resp.getBody())
}
```

In this code, data flow will be like this `feign Internal Stream -> Buffer -> ByteArray -> Buffer -> File`

How can I downalod and save a file memory-efficiently and faster way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR. Use `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` and Java NIO

According to [SpringDecoder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/94977691b87fca960133cd6953b5839c44753852/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/support/SpringDecoder.java#L56), Spring decode response using HttpMessageConverters

ResourceHttpMessageConverter which is one of HttpMesageConverters return [InputStreamResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html) which contain InputStream and filename derived from `Content-Disposition`.

But, ResourceHttpMessageConverter must be initialized `supportsReadStreaming = true (default value)`
If you have further interests on this implementation, [check this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2572cd0503c7d009d3f84c70799723c0f21c0697/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L81).

So, changed code are as followings:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/v1/files")
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@RequestParam(value = "key") String key)
```

#### JDK9

```java
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt")) {
    responeEntity.getBody().getInputStream().transferTo(os);
}
```

#### JDK8 or less

Use Guava [ByteStreams.copy()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-)

```java
Path p = Paths.get(responseEntity.getFilename())
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(responeEntity.getBody().getInputStream())
try(FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(p, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
    ByteStreams.copy(rbc, fc)
}
```

Now, `Feign Internal Stream -> File`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to fetch a stream from an external api using Feign.
You should use `ByteArrayResource` as the response type in your feign method.

In your feign interface make your method return `ByteArrayResource` to consume a stream

```
@FeignClient(name = "lim-service", url = "https://your-api.com/api)
public interface LimClient {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/files")
    ByteArrayResource getFile(@RequestParam(value = "key") String key);
}
```

---

A comment regarding the accepted answer:

You can `InputStreamResource` instead of `ByteArrayResource` only if the stream will be consumed only one time, if you need to consume the stream multiple times you shouldn't use `InputStreamResource`.

Quoting from `InputStreamResource` class **javadoc**:

> Should only be used if no other specific `Resource` implementation is applicable. In particular, prefer `ByteArrayResource` or any of the file-based `Resource` implementations where possible.

> In contrast to other `Resource` implementations, this is a descriptor for an *already opened* resource - therefore returning `true` from `isOpen()`.

> Do not use an `InputStreamResource` if you need to keep the resource descriptor somewhere, or **if you need to read from a stream multiple times**.